# Cursor turning into the pointer (hand) before visually reaching the icon

Tags: html, css

I've already checked the code on DevTools and it shows the problem:

[image: icon size on devtools]

The icon is actually wider than I would like. I've already tried changing its size, padding, margin, etc, but with no good results. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[Code can be found here](https://codepen.io/kaiohenricunha/pen/poErEbN)

```
<a href="#about">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: black";></i>
</a>
```

```
element.style {
  color: black;
}

.fa, .fas {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.fa-stack-1x` class on your icon. That will fix it. That class specifically is setting the width to be 100%. I removed it on my browser and it works fine with out it.

Comment: Additionally: if the goal was to make the icon larger, there are sizing classes specifically for that: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

Comment: Also, I understand now how icon classes work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this css code, this prevent icon to be larger (`width`) and to be centered (`left`):

```
.fa-stack-1x, .fa-stack-2x {
  left: inherit !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```js
const projectName = 'tribute-page';
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p, h1, h3, h4, cite, ul {
  color: #D9D4D0;
  font-family: font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #D9B384;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: url(https://media.gazetadopovo.com.br/2012/12/7cc68ffc5247e851268670d802a50453-gpMedium.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-vertical-center {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 #D9D4D0,
                  1px 1px 0 #D9D4D0,
                 1px -1px 0 #D9D4D0;
                -1px -1px 0 #D9D4D0;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.text-vertical-center h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}


element.style {
  color: black;
}

.fa, .fas {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.fa-stack-1x, .fa-stack-2x {
  left:inherit !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39c2eebbd7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Tribute to Caetano Veloso</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Neucha&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main id="main">
    <header class="header">
     <div class="text-vertical-center">
       <h1>Caetano Veloso</h1>
       <h3 id="subheading">an aging chameleon</h3>
       <a href="#about">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: black";></i>
       </a>
     </div> 
    </header>

    <section id="tribute-info" class="container">
      <h3 id="about">These are the main events in Caetano's life:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>1942</strong> - Born in Santo Amaro, Bahia, Brazil</li>
        <li>
          <strong>1959</strong> - Hears for the first time the song Chega de Saudade, by Bossa Nova's father João Gilberto. He later recalled: "It was the clearest landmark a song has ever left in my life"
        </li>
        <li>
        <strong>1963</strong> - First musical work. After impressing the director Álvaro Guimarães with a speech on how João Gilberto revitalized Samba, Caetano is invited to compose the soundtrack to the plays Boca de Ouro, by Nelson Rodrigues, and A Exceção e a Regra, by Bertold Bretch.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1965</strong> - Moves to Rio de Janeiro with his sister Maria Betânia
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1967</strong> - Releases, in a partnership with Gal Costa, his first album Domingo.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1967</strong> - Releases his first self-titled solo album, giving birth to the Tropicalist movement, which would change the history of Brazilian music.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1968</strong> - Caetano performs the provocative song É Proibido Proibir with Os Mutantes at the 3ª International Song Festival to a booing crowd. Caetano then improvises an angry, and now historical, speech against the judges and the public.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1968</strong> - Because of his political views, Caetano is sent to jail by the Military Regime.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1969</strong> - Caetano moves to England with his friend Gilberto Gil, where he lives in exile until 1972.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1971</strong> - Releases one of his best albums, the acclaimed Transa, which contained covers and songs with English subtitles.
        <li>
          <strong>1972</strong> - Returns to Brazil and performs with João Gilberto and Gal Costa at TV Tupi.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1980</strong> - Caetano starts growing in popularity abroad, especially in Portugal, Israel, France and Africa.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1983</strong> - Meets Paula Lavigne, who was 14 years old. She would later become his long-time wife, with whom Caetano had 2 kids.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>1990</strong> - Participates in the Montreaux Jazz Festival in Switzerland.
        </li>
        <li><strong>1991</strong> - Writes a profound article to the New York Times about the cultural implications of Carmem Miranda</li>
        <li>
          <strong>2002</strong> - Launches a book about the tropicalia movement, Tropical Truth: A Story of Music and Revolution in Brazil.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>2010</strong> - The artist becomes a constant meme object on the internet.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>2016</strong> - Caetano performs at the Rio Olimpic Games with Anitta.
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>2020</strong> - 
  Wins a millionaire judicial dispute against Olavo de Carvalho, the intellectual mentor of the Bolsonaro family
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="popular-albums-section" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="popular-albums-header">Caetano's best albums</h3>
          <div class="margin-bottom col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <h4><strong>Transa</strong> - 1972</h4>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transa_(album)" target="_blank"> <img class="album-photo img-responsive" src="images/caetanotransa.png" alt="Transa album cover"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="margin-bottom col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <h4><strong>Qualquer coisa</strong> - 1975</h4>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualquer_Coisa" target="_blank"> <img class="album-photo img-responsive" src="images/qualquercoisa.png" alt="Qualquer Coisa album cover"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="margin-bottom col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <h4><strong>Cinema Transcendental</strong> - 1979</h4>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_Transcendental" target="_blank"> <img class="album-photo img-responsive" src="images/Cinema_Transcendental_cover.png" alt="Cinema Transcendental Cover"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="margin-bottom col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <h4><strong>Bicho</strong> - 1977</h4>
            <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicho_(%C3%A1lbum)" target="_blank"> <img class="album-photo img-responsive" src="images/Capa_de_Bicho.png" alt="Bicho album cover"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="margin-bottom col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
            <h4><strong>Cores, Nomes</strong> - 1982</h4>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cores,_Nomes" target="_blank"> <img class="album-photo img-responsive" src="images/coresnomescover.png" alt="Cores, Nomes album cover"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>
        "When imagined by American critics, the most frequent cliché used about the legendary singer Caetano Veloso is that he is the Bob Dylan of Brazil. In that case, the best Dylan song to associate with Veloso would be "Forever Young," because Veloso is one of the most restlessly creative, forward-looking musicians of our time."
      </p>
      <cite>-- Author Ed Morales</cite>
    </blockquote>
      <h3>If you're interested, you should read more about this incredible human being on his
      <a id="tribute-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caetano_Veloso" target="_blank">Wikipedia entry</a>.
    </h3>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise using `!important` to override CSS if there are alternative options; makes the CSS harder to maintain later.

Comment: A little more complicated, but it works too. Thanks!